# Wiretap router versus Async scope

Tags: mule, mule-studio

Based on my understanding of the [Wire Tap router](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routers) (scroll to bottom of the link) and the [Async scope](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Async+Scope+Reference), I think there is significant overlap in the functionality that they both provide.

Similarities

- Both create a copy of the message and send it across to MP's
- The original flow continues to execute on a separate thread

I am looking for some guidelines to understand when to use which feature.

Also even though the wire-tap router is documented it is not available in Mule studio Version 5.1.0 is it deprecated ?

[image: Mule Studio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `async`, `wire-tap` is legacy and inherited from older versions of mule. The implications are at the threading level, specially the difference is from which internal thread pool they take the thread from.

Please bear in mind that its use should be very simple, otherwise it may end up being a bottleneck in higher loads.

Comment: Would appreciate if you expand on "specially the difference is from which internal thread pool they take the thread from" or point me to some resources around this

Comment: This is part of internals and I don't believe it is documented, but you can play with it using Java Visual VM and creating a sample app that logs the thread name, and maybe it calls Thread.sleep within expression components.

Answer (score 0):

wiretap:

1.there is no specific component available in anypoint studio but its xml based     declaration.
2.only one message processor can be defined in wiretap router.

Async Scope:

1.a specific component available in any-point studio.
2.is support the definition of more than one message processor.

As per documentation the working nature of both components works as defined.

Comment: If I use a processor chain or flow ref in wire tap it will allow multiple MPs, my question is whether there is use case were any one should be preferred over the other and why